# Package microtype has no effect

Tags: formatting, packages

The package "microtype" seems to have no effect, especially the tracking for small caps. I work with Texmaker.

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{my}{font=*/*/*/sc/*}
\SetTracking{encoding=*,shape=sc}{500}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Einleitung}

Ein gerades Gebilde $ABC$ und ein Ebenenbüschel $PQR$, dessen Axe $s$ mit
dem Träger $u$ des geraden Gebildes keinen Punkt gemein hat, sollen in einem
und demselben Sinne beschrieben heissen, wenn in dem geraden Gebilde der Sinn
$u(PQR)$ mit dem Sinne $ABC$ und also in dem Ebenenbüschel der Sinn $s(ABC)$
mit dem Sinne $PQR$ übereinstimmt.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using pdfTeX? This `microtype` feature doesn't work under XeTeX.

Comment: The code example is missing a document class, but if I add `\documentclass{article}` and compile with pdfLaTeX (`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` should not be used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, so pdfLaTeX seemed to be the best guess) I see a stark effect of `\SetTracking{encoding=*,shape=sc}{500}` in `\textsc{Einleitung}`. Please add a `\documentclass` to your code example, upload a screenshot of the result when you compile this exact example and add any warning or errors from your log file to your question. If you want you upload the entire log to a website such as https://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 3):

My problem is solved. Your answer brought me to the right track: When I was inserting the `\documentclass`, I realised that I hat the `draft` option:

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}
```

For this reason the microtype package does not work. After removing the `draft` option (or leaving it and setting the `final` option for the `microtype` package) all works. Thank you very much!